# dropdown menu stops working after page jump

Tags: javascript, css, menu, drop-down-menu

My head is about to explode as I try to figure out the reason why my dropdown menu stops working as soon as the page jumps to an anchor. There is some JS involved in the jump, too, but the same problem existed even with a plain html anchor jump.

The page is at http://mincovlawyer.com/doc/euro-excellence

As you load the page, please hover over "The Law", "About" and "The Goodies" and see how the dropdown is supposed to operate.

Then click any of the links in the sidebox to the right, for example Alt. #1.

Then hover over the menu items again and observe that no dropdowns emerge anymore.

I would immensely appreciate any guidance in this regard.

Comment: without clicking also it is hiding,you can scroll a page,drop down going upward in chrome.For find that you can mousover a Goodies and scroll a mouse.menu going upwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rollover breaks even if you just scroll down the page. The rollover menu is positioned absolute and the navigation is positioned fixed. You could add 'position:fixed' to your rollover menu or you could add the scroll offset in your drop down menu code.

To set 'position:fixed':
At line 8 of the anylinkmenu.css file, change the position:absolute to position:fixed.

Comment: this was simple :) now i'd only need to add an ie6 fix and i'll be set. thank you

Answer (score 1):

It looks like they're working, but they are above the top of the page. Before clicking on any of the links, scroll down just a little bit. Then hover over "The Law" and you'll see your menu shifted vertically.

Comment: this is brilliant, you are right. now if only i could get that fixed somehow. I suppose it would require subtracting the scrolled pixels from the position of the menu, but i'm really sure how to do it

Comment: now that you've discovered this, i realize that this problem persists on all pages. as soon as I scroll down a page, the dropdown menu scrolls up

Answer (score 0):

Now that's a lot of code...
Where's your menu created? The mouse-over stuff

Question1:
Why even using any javascript for an inline-anchor? Using #links scrolls to said position anyways, even without JS?!

Comment: i use javascript because of the fixed header on top. the anchor by itself results in the beginning portion of the relevant section to be hidden by the header